# Anspress Customization: How to show logged in user votes on a single answer?

Tags: plugins, customization

I am using Anspress plugin in my website. I customized the plugin to show the answers on a single question page.
 [image: Your vote displays the current users vote and Votes in the box shows total votes on answer]

Now my problem is, I am unable to find a function which can display the current user votes on a particular answer along with ajax load. I created my own function and overrided it but it do not load using ajax. I have to reload a page to show the vote of a user when a user clicks on vote button.

Also when I click on vote button now it displays the current total votes + user's 1 vote.

Please give me right path.

Let have a look on my own function to show a user's vote on an answer.

```
function my_ap_how_many_vote_on_a_post($userid, $postid)
{
    global $wpdb;
    if(!$userid)
    {
        $userid = get_current_user_id();
    }
    $totalvotesonaquestion = 'SELECT apmeta_type as type, IFNULL(count(*), 0) as count FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'ap_meta WHERE apmeta_type = "vote_up" and apmeta_userid = "' . $userid . '" and apmeta_actionid = "' . $postid . '" GROUP BY apmeta_type';
    $maxcountholder      = $wpdb->get_results($totalvotesonaquestion);
    if($maxcountholder[0]->count > 0)
        return $maxcountholder[0]->count;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

I am waiting for helping one.

Comment: I am waiting for a helpful answer guys........

Comment: Guys I am still waiting for a helping answer...........